# Request method 'POST' not supported in spring MVC web app

Tags: spring, methods

i am using .html in mvc app. it's showing app perfectly.inside login.html i have used form with method POST for submission but when i submit form showing error that POST is not supported.but when i change everything with .jsp then it let submit form.

here's the controller

```java
    @Controller
public class mainController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(Locale locale , Model m) {
        System.out.println("modal");
        return new ModelAndView ("login");  
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/user" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String user(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        System.out.println(user);
        return "user";
    }
}
```

this is login form

```xml
<form action="user" method="post" name="user">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="uname"/> <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/> <br>
    <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="date"/> <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>   
</form>
```

what can I do to submit form using POST method from .html file.

Comment: did you tried `/user` in html form action? Also, add `@ResponseBody` to user method.

Comment: issue resolved with @ResponseBody Thank you